# How do I iterate all stores?

Tags: localforage

I'm using [localForage](https://github.com/localForage/localForage) and I'm creating a bunch of different stores using `localforage.createInstance`.

Now I need to iterate these stores. I'm not able to keep track of what stores gets created, so I need that localForage to give me a list of the stores but I can't find anything like this in the API.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No unfortunately there is nothing like this currently available.
[Here is the issue](https://github.com/localForage/localForage/issues/573) that currently tracks that request.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but...
The issue in github are forgotten.

```
async function getStoreNames() {
//Create some stores with localforage
let store1 = await localforage.createInstance({
    name: "yourDBName",
    storeName: "store1"
});
let store2 = await localforage.createInstance({
    name: "yourDBName",
    storeName: "store2"
});
let store3 = await localforage.createInstance({
    name: "yourDBName",
    storeName: "store3"
});
await store1.setItem("aaa", "aaa")//add something on stores
await store2.setItem("bbb", "bbb")
await store3.setItem("ccc", "ccc")

//With store fully initialized (can be any in yourDBName) get the stores names, can be the blob test store.
//Filter names if needed.
let storeNames = Array.from(store1._dbInfo.db.objectStoreNames).filter(x => !x.startsWith("l"))
console.log(storeNames);
return storeNames;
}

getStoreNames()//Remember the store must be working
```